# mongodb , node.js, combbo, deploying on heroku, mongod

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I am new to mongodb and node.js. I have a simple node.js app that in order to run I have to run the command

```
mongod
```

to make sure mongodb is running. 
locally this works fine.

now I am moving to heroku, I createrd a Procfile where I declare :

```
  web: node http.js
```

so this take care of starting node.js.

Now how can I call the command

```
   mongod
```

on heroku?

### Update

before the heroku requirement this is how I used to initialize my mongodb :

```
 var mongo = require('mongodb');
 var Server = mongo.Server,
 Db = mongo.Db,
 BSON = mongo.BSONPure,
 ObjectID = mongo.ObjectID;
 var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
 db = new Db('sampledb', server);
 db.open(function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
     console.log("Connected to 'sampledb' database");
     db.collection('sample', {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
         if (err) {
            console.log("The 'sample' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
            populateDB();
        }
    });
  }
});
```

in order to accomodate heroku here is how I initialize mongodb :

```
 var mongo = require('mongodb');
 var Server = mongo.Server,
 Db = mongo.Db,
 BSON = mongo.BSONPure,
 ObjectID = mongo.ObjectID;
   var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
   process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
   'mongodb://localhost/sampledb';
   mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function (err, db) {
   db.collection('sample', function(er, collection) {
     if (err) {
                  console.log("The 'sample' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with   
          sample data...");
                  populateDB();
               }
  });
 });
```

Now this throws an error because db is not recognized. I think I am missing a conceptual issue here, I am new to this world all together.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't call the command `mongod` on heroku.

You'd add one of the mongo add-ons from addons.heroku.com to your app, then have your code connect to the credentials in the config variable exported to your app by the add-on provider.